# Three.js - Remove the head of an ArrowHelper

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have created in my code an ArrowHelper and I update its parameters by calling the function below (each call of this function updates the ArrowHelper dimensions) :

```
function updateArrowHelper() {

    // Update parameters for transportedVector
    transportedVector.arrowHelper.setLength(transportedVector.coordLocal.length(), headLengthVector, headWidthVector);
  transportedVector.arrowHelper.setDirection(directionVector.normalize());
  transportedVector.arrowHelper.position.copy(coordTorus);
  transportedVector.arrowHelper.line.material.linewidth = widthVector;
  transportedVector.arrowHelper.setColor(hexVector);
  // Set head length and width to zero if dirVector.length is zero
  if (transportedVector.coordLocal.length() == 0.0)
        transportedVector.arrowHelper.setLength(0, 0, 0);    
}
```

I would like to make disappear the head of `ArrowHelper` if its length (given by `transportedVector.coordLocal.length()`) is zero, what I have done with :

```
 // Set head length and width to zero if dirVector.length is zero
      if (transportedVector.coordLocal.length() == 0.0)
        transportedVector.arrowHelper.setLength(0, 0, 0);
```

But at the execution, this doesn't work : even the length is null, once function is called, the head is still displayed and I don't know why ?

If anyone could see what's wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about `arrowHelper.cone.visible = false;`

Comment: Thanks, that does the trick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can hide the head of the `ArrowHelper`by using this pattern:

```
arrowHelper.cone.visible = false;
```

three.js r.80